# Title left alignment with PGFPlots in Julia

Tags: julia, center, title, text-alignment, pgfplots

I use PGFPlots.jl package in Julia to produce figures. I would like to have the title of figure being left aligned [instead of being centered by default]. Here is my MWE in Julia language:

```
using PGFPlots
p = Plots.Linear3(rand(10), rand(10), rand(10), mark = "none")
Axis(p, title = "(a)")
```

The title of the obtained figure is aligned center by default. How could I modify the above Julia code to have the title "(a)" being left aligned?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I opened an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaTeX/PGFPlots.jl/issues/160. please follow there for updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PGFPlots.Axis` offers the keyword argument `style`, where you can paste options for pgfplots.

In your case, you can anchor the title at the top left (i.e., north west) of the bounding box.

```
using PGFPlots
p = Plots.Linear3(rand(10), rand(10), rand(10), mark = "none")
a = Axis(p, title="(a)", style="title style={at={(current bounding box.north west)}, anchor=west}")
```

**Background: PGFPlots.jl in general**

To achieve much more with PGFPlots.jl, I recommend inspecting the LaTeX code generated by the package. You can then consult the many resources already available for pgfplots.

```
println(PGFPlots.tikzCode(a))
```

The first lines of the output will be:

```tex
\begin{axis}[
  title = {(a)},
  title style={at={(current bounding box.north west)}, anchor=west}
]

...
```

As you can see, the `style` argument we provided is simply pasted as options of the `axis` environment. If you find out how to alter your plots in the pgfplots backend, you can immediately apply this knowledge through the `style` argument.

Many examples of great plots are given in [the documentation of PGFPlots.jl](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JuliaTeX/PGFPlots.jl/blob/master/doc/PGFPlots.ipynb)